# E-clip (temporary) alternative?

Tags: substitute-tool, hardware

Does anyone know a trick to replace an e-clip while waiting for the shipment of a replacement?

An e-clip is a kind of [circlip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circlip)

An E-Clip is a kind of shaft mounted retaining ring, which provides a larger than average retaining surface. It looks like this:

[image: E-clip]

(A snap ring looks like this:)

[image: Snap ring]

Comment: What it is to be used for?

Comment: @Lawrence it's a general question : how to retain a shaft with a groove? (The hack could fix a motor or the drive train of a bicycle)

Comment: The same hack might not fix all situations. For something simple with little stress/speed, a length of wire twisted around the shaft, in the groove, might do it. The question (with comment) is almost "why do we need e-clips?"

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right, I tried it. But in the specific case, I'm dealing with right now (the drive train of a bicycle): the groove is quite thin, so I need to use a thin wire, which isn't large enough to block the piece in a robust manner (it works, but it doesn't look really solid).

Comment: EDIT: the thin wire technic still works after 2 years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the application but I've done this before using mild steel; I cut a U shaped notch into a plate, the internal diameter of the U being a tight fit for the groove in the shaft, then bent one of the fingers of the plate so as to retain it on the shaft. It's not a high stress application; it retains the wheel on a lawn tractor

[image]

[image]

I've achieved similar results before using some steel wire wrapped around the shaft and twist locked, and in some cases I've drilled through the shaft and used a washer and split pin arrangement instead of an e clip

Answer (score 3):

I just lost a very small circlip putting a turntable back together.  It shot across the room into a pile that will never give it up.  I took a piece of copper wire that was the same diameter as the slot in the post, wrapped it around the post and twisted the ends.....Done!  I am still buying a box of 300 circlips to do it right.  300 circlips for $6!  How can you go wrong?

Comment: Actually, I did the same 2 years ago (with a basic single-strand wire twisted with a plier). The circlips arrived a few weeks later, but since the wire was happily doing its job, I did not remove it. So, the circlip wasn't needed. The wire trick has been working for 2 years with frequent use of the bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, you could simply use [tin solder](https://youtu.be/iQuz1lmysYQ?t=363) (which can easily be removed when needed):
[image]